# trying to insert image into database getting ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested error

Tags: java, database, image, jsp, insert

I'm trying to insert an image into database and with auto increment photo_id.

my table columns are:

```
PHOTO_ID  (primary key),
USERNAME  (fkey),
PICTURE,
PICTURE_TITLE,
LIKES
```

my code is

```
public class UploadPhotoDao {
    public int insertPhoto(UploadPhotoBean uploadBean){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        int index = 0;
        final String query = "INSERT INTO PHOTOS_DETAILS (PHOTO_ID,USERNAME,PICTURE,PICTURE_TITLE,LIKES) VALUES (PHOTO_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval,?,?,?,?)";
            try {
                con = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);


                ps.setString(1, uploadBean.getUsername());
                File file =new File(uploadBean.getPicture());
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, fis.available());
                ps.setString(3, uploadBean.getPictureTitle());
                ps.setInt(4, new Integer(0));
                index = ps.executeUpdate();

            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally {
                    ConnectionUtil.closeQuitly(ps);
                    ConnectionUtil.closeQuitly(con);
            }
            return index;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

Comment: Does your insert statement work if you omit the BLOB column? Does it work if you provide NULL for the BLOB column?

Comment: solved this problem..just a ojdbc14.jar file problem...need to get latest version. thats it

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream.available()` does ***not*** return the size of the stream (which is clearly documented in the Javadocs).

You will need to query the size of the file, not the "available bytes" in the inputstream:

```
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length());
```

depending on the version of your JDBC driver you can also use

```
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, file.length());
```

But `setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, long)` is defined in JDBC 4.0 and thus not implemented by all driver versions. `setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, int)` is JDBC 2.0 (if I'm not mistaken) and should be available in all versions.

Comment: getting same error even i changed to ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length()); plz check my query...is there any errors??? i declated my picture column as BLOB in db table. and im using a sequence to auto increment photo id column.....

Comment: @user1900771: sorry, then I don't have any more ideas

Comment: hi...i solved this problem...its a just driver problem ..changed ojdbc14.jar to latest version.