# How to resolve ORA-01460 Error?

Tags: oracle, servlets, jdbc

I am uploading photos to oracle database.The code for my AddPhotoServlet class is as follows.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class AddPhotoServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        // Apache Commons-Fileupload library classes
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload sfu  = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        /*if (! ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            System.out.println("sorry. No file uploaded");
            return;
        }*/

        // parse request
        List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);
        FileItem  id = (FileItem) items.get(0);
        String photoid =  id.getString();

        FileItem title = (FileItem) items.get(1);
        String   phototitle =  title.getString();

        // get uploaded file
        FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(2);

        // Connect to Oracle
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "cloud", "cloud");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into photos values(?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, photoid);
        ps.setString(2, phototitle);
        // size must be converted to int otherwise it results in error
        ps.setBinaryStream(3, file.getInputStream(), (int) file.getSize());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        con.close();
        out.println("Proto Added Successfully. <p> <a href='listphotos'>List Photos </a>");
    }
```

When i run the html page in the server while uploading it throws the error :
  ORA-01460:unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested.
Can anyone please help me with this ?

I have created my table as :

```
create table photos
(
id number(5) primary key,
title varchar2(50),
photo blob
);
```

Comment: In this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194165/trying-to-insert-image-into-database-getting-ora-01460-unimplemented-or-unreaso it is suggested (in the comments) to update to the latest version of your Oracle jdbc driver. Have you tried that?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian No I have not tried that but i'll sure do now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the oracle jdbc developer's guide for working with [streams](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jstreams.htm#JJDBC28409) and [lobs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oralob.htm#JJDBC28535). There are quite a few options on how the data is handled that has different performance/memory implications.
One portion of the second doc (on lobs) covers the use of temporary lob objects by using [Connection.createBlob()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob%28%29) and writing the content to that object and then setting that blob object on the statement.