# Can't save BLOB to database (ORA-01460: Unimplemented or not meaningful conversion required)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, blob, prepared-statement

I have this table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqPublicFile START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE PublicFile(
  fileId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  fileName varchar2(50),
  fileContent blob,
  publishDate date,
  publisherTeacher varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT fk_teacher1 FOREIGN KEY(publisherTeacher) REFERENCES Teacher(username)
);
```

When I try saving a new row into my table:

```
conn = createConnection();
String select = "INSERT INTO PublicFile VALUES(seqPublicFile.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(select);
stmt.setString(1, "fs1.jpg");
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\schueler\\Desktop\\5AHIFS\\NVS\\fs1.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
stmt.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());
stmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
stmt.setString(4, "nimda");
stmt.executeQuery();
conn.close();
```

I always get this error:

```
ORA-01460: Unimplemented or not meaningful conversion required
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried also getBytes and I tried reading the file in a different way but every try leads to the same error.

How can I simple read a file and save it as a blob?

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: @Andreas ojdbc14

Comment: your issue is on `setBinaryStream` maybe the length of the image is being more then 4000 byte. can you try with a small image? also make sure your driver is updated to latest

Comment: @Moudiz it works for files smaller than 4mb. but why cant I save files larger than 4mb. in c# I can do that

Comment: Update to newer driver and it'll work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194165/trying-to-insert-image-into-database-getting-ora-01460-unimplemented-or-unreaso#comment19678946_14194302